# Как dstat узнает высоту экрана консоли?

Tags: linux, консоль

Программа [dstat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dstat) выводит шапку таблицы, а потом построчно актуальные значения раз в определенный интервал времени:

```
----total-cpu-usage---- -dsk/total- -net/total- ---paging-- ---system--
usr sys idl wai hiq siq| read  writ| recv  send|  in   out | int   csw
  0   1  98   0   0   1|   0     0 |7884B 1058B|   0     0 | 334   266
  0   1  99   0   0   0|   0     0 |8565B 1660B|   0     0 | 324   276
  0   1  99   0   0   0|   0     0 |6996B  590B|   0     0 | 325   240
  0   0  99   0   0   1|   0     0 |6718B  992B|   0     0 | 348   236
  1   1  98   0   0   0|   0     0 |7116B  964B|   0     0 | 408   276
  0   1  99   0   0   0|   0     0 |6500B  468B|   0     0 | 343   221
  0   0  99   0   0   1|   0     0 |6136B  830B|   0     0 | 318   217
```

Интересно, что когда шапка таблицы уходит вверх, за пределы окна консоли, то сразу же появляется новая. Выглядит так, как будто dstat знает высоту окна и в нужный момент снова отправляет две строки с шапкой.

Я пробовал менять высоту после запуска dstat. Программа подстраивается и снова отправляет шапку в нужное время.

Как это происходит? Какой-то код выполняется на стороне клиента? Консоль предоставляет размеры окна по какому-нибудь протоколу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если говорить про эту конкретную программу, написанную на языке *python*, то в начале своего выполнения она «прощупывает почву» [в функции initterm()](https://github.com/dagwieers/dstat/blob/master/dstat#L2246):

1. сначала делается попытка выполнить [ioctl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl)-запрос [TIOCGWINSZ](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_495.html). если он проходит удачно, то при последующих вызовах [функции gettermsize()](https://github.com/dagwieers/dstat/blob/master/dstat#L2269) будет получать размеры терминала именно *ioctl*-запросом
2. при неудаче делается попытка обращения к библиотеке [curses](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses). если удачно, у неё впоследствии и будут запрашиваться данные о размере терминала
3. если и тут неудача, то впоследствии будет предприниматься попытка получить размеры из переменных окружения (см. ниже)
4. в самом тяжёлом случае — [константы 25 и 80](https://github.com/dagwieers/dstat/blob/master/dstat#L2286)

---

теперь про «вообще».

например, прямо в интерактивной сессии оболочки (проверял в *bash* и *zsh*) можно обратиться к переменным окружения `COLUMNS` и `LINES` (они устанавливаются оболочкой и динамически меняются при изменении размеров терминала):

```
$ echo $LINES $COLUMNS
```

внутри программы/скрипта, помимо упомянутых выше низкоуровневых средств можно воспользоваться программами *stty* или *tput*. кстати, при изменении размеров терминала эмулятор терминала обычно посылает сигнал [SIGWINCH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGWINCH) запущенному в нём процессу. обычно это процесс оболочки, который, в свою очередь, пересылает сигнал и запущенным дочерним процессам.

иллюстрирующий пример скрипта (должен работать, по идее, в любой posix-совместимой оболочке):

```
/bin/echo -e "начальные значения:\nstty size: $(stty size); \
tput lines: $(tput lines); tput cols: $(tput cols)"

trap '/bin/echo -e "получен сигнал WINCH!\nstty size: $(stty size); \
tput lines: $(tput lines); tput cols: $(tput cols)"' WINCH

while :; do sleep 3
  /bin/echo -e "текущие значения:\nstty size: $(stty size); \
tput lines: $(tput lines); tput cols: $(tput cols)"
done
```

после запуска можно увидеть, как при изменении размеров окна эмулятора терминала был сначала (после завершения очередного вызова внешней программы — `sleep`) обработан сигнал *WINCH*, а уж потом выведены текущие значения:

```
начальные значения:
stty size: 28 81; tput lines: 28; tput cols: 81
текущие значения:
stty size: 28 81; tput lines: 28; tput cols: 81
получен сигнал WINCH!
stty size: 30 81; tput lines: 30; tput cols: 81
текущие значения:
stty size: 30 81; tput lines: 30; tput cols: 81
^C
```